# Cannot delete mail from storage in Usage section of IPhone

Tags: iphone

In the usage section of IPhone 5 it says I have 349MB inn Mail.  However, I have deleted ALL inbox, sent, trash etc...there is nothing in the mail.  How do I get the Storage in the Usage section to empty this mail?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting the phone. Press and hold Home+Sleep until the Apple logo appears.

If that doesn't work, and the email account you are using with Mail is *not* connected using POP3, then try removing the email account and re-adding it. Go to Settings app > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > tap on the specific account > Delete Account. Confirm that you want to delete it, and reboot the phone - press and hold Home + Sleep until the Apple logo appears. Re-add the account by going to Settings app > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account.

Answer (score 0):

Tubedogg is correct, but I would like to add that his method for rebooting the phone actually **forces** the phone to reboot. This is good for when the phone is non-responsive or you are doing other troubleshooting steps. But it should not be **necessary** for most applications, including this one. Simply holding down the Sleep button (at the top of the phone, or side if it is a 6/6+) until you get a control that tells you to slide to power off. That is a graceful shutdown.

Removing the account may work and is worth a try. failing that you may want to backup the phone then wipe it: Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase all content and settings. Once it is wiped, just restore from the backup you just made.

Doing that cleared up a lot of free space on my phone (a 5 with 8.1).

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see this before, but anyway: power cycling the phone is akin to logging out and back into your account on the computer. It does _not_ run "reboot" tasks, like clearing memory caches, or permanently deleting caches or app data that are "soft deleted" in response to a user action like removing an email account or deleting an app.